# How to break down who did what in AにBをCさせる

Tags: particles, syntax

I'm trying to understand the following:

> 後輩にサイフを開かせることはないよ

I guess this could be generalized as AにBをCさせる.

It's confusing. Maybe if someone can break down how to understand this and then I can memorize it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually, you have a sentence like:

> 後輩がサイフを開く
>   koohai ga saihu wo hirak-u
>   'the junior opens the wallet'

where the subject takes `が` and the object takes `を`.

There is a morpheme `-(s)ase-` 'let', 'make' that expresses causative. The way you use it is that you embed the sentence, and change the embedded subject `が` into `に`, take another subject that will be the causer.

> 君が後輩にサイフを開かせる
>   kimi ga [koohai **ni** saihu wo hirak]-ase-ru
>   'you let [the junior open the wallet]'

In your example, the subject `君が` is actually omitted, so you have

> 後輩にサイフを開かせる

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes i  *process* it like this:

(Zが) トムが: **Tom**

(Aに) 後輩に: *towards* / *unto* **junior**

(Bを) サイフを: *take* / *consume* **wallet**

(Cさせる) 開かせる: *let* / *made* + **open**

= Tom let/made junior open the wallet.