# What is the らせ form of a verb?

Tags: verbs, meaning, conjugations

I'm trying to understand this:

賞品？おそらく！リナちゃん.....私の後ろの笑い声輝くん​がたくさんで黙らせ

The last word, 黙らせ, is confusing. Is this a combination of different forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`黙らせる` is the causative form of the verb `黙る`. See [my explanation to your previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/) for the meaning of the causative `-(s)ase-`

> damar-u [Original form]
> BeQuiet-NonPast
>
> damar-**ase**-ru [Causative]
> BeQuiet-Causative-NonPast

Comment: You should link to the previous question.  Just because these posts are chronologically close doesn't mean someone who only looks at this one will be able to find the other one.

Comment: Why does it end in あせ and not あせる？

Comment: @language_hacker I don't know. Are you sure that your example is accurate? It can be used as a part of a sequence like, `黙らせ、食べさせ、...`.

Comment: Yes, that is how it appears. What does it say?

Comment: The source you relied on does not seem to be spelled correctly. It may be that `る` was just missed.

Comment: If that's the case, then what does it say?

Comment: What does リナちゃん.....私の後ろの笑い声輝くん​がたくさんで黙らせ say?

Comment: @language_hacker It is not a grammatical sentence. I cannot parse it. 'Rina-chan', 'laughter behind my back', 'Many Teru-kun', 'Let someone shut up'

Comment: Can't it be something like "voices are ringing out behind me, but as there are a lot, I want them to shut up"? That would be 黙らせたい, with the tweet-length cut :)
Though I don't know if 声が輝く.

Comment: @Axioplase That is likely to be the case. `輝` is most likely pronounced 'Teru', and is a boy's name. @language_hacker, you really need to check the accuracy of your examples when you post. I do not care whether it is a tweet or not, but you have to take care of such anomaly if that results from the limitation of the media of your source.

Comment: @sawa: Agreed that language hacker needs to be more careful to post relevant questions. However, with much respect and appreciation for the fact that you are helping generate traffic and helpful answers on the site, you could do a lot to stop language hacker from posting irrelevant tweets by not rushing to answer every time he posts. You seem to try to answer no matter what the quality of his question, and the presence of your answer gives more validity than it deserves. This question should have been ignored. Please consider that always responding might encourage more poor questions.

Comment: @Dave_M_G Okay. I understand.